# Header and ul when resizing

Tags: jquery, html, css, resize

I'm trying to build my portfolio site and I'm having an issue trying to get my header and nav menu to stack on top of each other when the page is smaller, and go back to normal otherwise.

Here is my HTML code.

```
<body class="container" id="boostrap-overrides">

<a id="name" href="#">Jasmine Parson</a>
 <ul id="list" class="nav justify-content-end">
  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
   <a  id="mid" class="nav-link" href="#">Work</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

All Relevant CSS

```
#boostrap-overrides ul {
 flex-wrap: nowrap;

}

.center {
 text-align: center;
}

ul {
 float:right;   
 display: inline;
 line-height: 15px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

My jQuery

```
   $(window).resize(function(){
 if($(window).width() <= 700){
   $("#list").removeClass("justisfy-content-end");
   $("#list").addClass("justisfy-content-center");
 } 
});
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? Which version? I see bootstrap override in your comments

Comment: The latest version. 4.

Answer (score 0):

**try this one>>>**

```
    <a id="name" href="#">Jasmine Parson</a>
     <ul id="list" class="nav justify-content-end">
      <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
       <a  id="mid" class="nav-link" href="#">Work</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
     </li>
    </ul>

//CSS
    #boostrap-overrides ul {
     flex-wrap: nowrap;

    }

    .center {
     text-align: center;
    }
    .justify-content-end li{
    float:left;
    }
    ul {
     float:right;   
     display: inline;
     line-height: 15px;
     margin: 0 auto;
    }

//JS
     if($(window).width() <= 700){
       $("#list").removeClass("justisfy-content-end");
       $("#list").addClass("justisfy-content-center");
     } 
    });
```

Comment: That didn't work. the header and ul just stay right next to each other the entire time I'm shrinking the window. The ul just drops down a line when the window is at its smallest, but never overlaps with the header.